# MFC ActiveX keystrokes

Tags: mfc

I have created an mfc activex control and want to handle the keystrokes. To handle keystrokes in child dialog. I override the pretranslate message in my child dialog class. To use pretranslate function in an activex control I have added hook.

As solution for the similar problem described at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194294.

Now pretranslate function is calling but the problem when I press the ESC key or enter key, an assertion come at ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));at wincore.cpp line 880.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you use a function in PreTranslateMessage that assumes that the window is created. Put

```
if (!::IsWindow(m_hWnd)) { return 0; }
```

in the beginning of your PreTranslateMessage and see if that helps.